# editing .bat file to open folders

Tags: batch-file

First, here is what I have:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "X:\CNC\2_NewPrograms"
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "X:\PRINTS"
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "X:"
```

This opens up 3 folders that I regularly use. I want to specify where in the monitor they should appear, and the height and width of each window. Is there a way to specify such a thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could look at [**nircmd**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to help do that

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible using just a .bat file.
I mean, to my knowledge, Windows does not come with anything out of the box that allow you to do this.

You may need to create a small app that will do it. I believe the function you'll need to use will be SetConsoleWindowInfo() :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686125%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do what you asked for but it may help you in your task.
It opens several windows and then tiles them.

```
::SideBySide.cmd by Todd Vargo
@echo off
call :Min >"%temp%.\tmp.vbs"
cscript /nologo "%temp%.\tmp.vbs"
start www.google.com
start notepad.exe
start taskmgr
start resmon
ping -n 8 127.0.0.1 >nul
call :Tile >"%temp%.\tmp.vbs"
cscript /nologo "%temp%.\tmp.vbs"
del "%temp%.\tmp.vbs"
goto :eof

:Min
echo CreateObject("shell.application").MinimizeAll
goto :eof

:Tile
echo CreateObject("shell.application").TileVertically
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Winsplit Revolution](http://winsplit-revolution.com/) to remember position of windows and automatically tile them etc.